# Suppose $R$ is a partial order on set $A$, and $B \subseteq A$. Prove theorems about the uniqueness of the smallest element

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

> Suppose $R$ is a partial order on set $A$, and $B \subseteq A$. Prove
>
> 1. If B has a smallest element, then this smallest element is unique. Thus, we can speak of the smallest element of B rather than a smallest
>      element.
> 2. Suppose b is the smallest element of B. Then b is also a minimal element of B, and it is the only minimal element.

My attempt:

1.

Suppose $x \in B$ and $x$ is smallest element. Suppose $x$ is not unique. Then there is one more smallest element, call it $y$, where $x≠y$.

Since $x$ is smallest element, $(x,y) \in R$

And since $y$ is smallest element, $(y,x) \in R$

Since $x ≠ y$, and $(x,y), (y,x)$ both in $R$, we conclude that $R$ is symmetric. But we know that $R$ is partial order, which implies it must antisymmetric. Hence we have a contradiction, which means $x$ must be unique.

2.

Suppose $b$ is the smallest element.

Suppose $b$ is not a minimal element. It means that there is some $x$, where $x ≠ b$ and $(x,b) \in R$. But since $(b,x) \in R $, it would imply that $R$ is symmetric, but we know it's not. Hence $b$ is a minimal element.

Suppose $b$ is not the only minimal element. Then there exists one more minimal element, say $x$, such that $x ≠ b$. It follows that neither $(x,b) \in R$ nor $(b,x) \in R$. But this is a contradiction, since we know that $b$ is a smallest element, and by definition of smallest element we have

$$\forall x \in B (bRx)$$

Which implies that $(b,x) \in R$. Hence $b$ is the only minimal element. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: You can't conclude that $R$ is symmetric, but only that it is not anti-symmetric, hence the contradiction. Otherwise it seems OK.

Comment: @armsa You are right, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: A fun way to think of this (which in this case is only a more pedantic way of stating things, but which can be interesting as an illustration of category theory) is to see a preorder as a category. A smalllest element is then an initial object in this category, and therefore is unique up to isomorphism (which is the more general statement that implies 1.). This is not of course exhaustive but an invitation to look up these basic notions in category theory.

Comment: 1 carries a smell of "proof by contradiction because contradiction proofs are nice". Why not just say you have $x$ and $y$ which are both smallest? Then antisymmetry of $R$ proves they must be equal. Direct proof, one abstraction level gone. Win-win. (Also note that, in addition to what amrsa said above, there is no contradiction between antisymmetry and symmetry. A relation can be both, as evidenced by the partial order $=$.) In 2, contradiction seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Arthur You are right. If I have a choice between direct proof and contradiction, chances are I will choose contradiction. Do you think it's better to choose direct proof?

Comment: Personally, aesthetically, yes. Mathematically, logically, it doesn't really matter.